# Crossmint does not register contract

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, nft, crossmint

I got an error while Registering Smart contract in Crossmint [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Mt9h.png) even if my contract is verified [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LNwo.png) but Crossmint show this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL7SH.png)

I've tried multiple NFT contracts but nothing works.

Comment: Please edit the question to ensure images show, or copy the messages text inline.thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must ensure you're using our https://staging.crossmint.com/console dev console when setting up testnet/devnet contracts.

You'll run into this problem  if you're trying to register a goerli (eth) or mumbai (polygon) contract in our production system. https://www.crossmint.com/console

Mainnet contracts are registered in our production console and testnet/devnet contracts are registered in our staging console.

This should get you back on track!